# Multiple Microsoft accounts in a browser

Tags: outlook.com, onedrive, microsoft-account

My company has a Microsoft account, and I see no way how I can access the company Onedrive/Outlook without logging out from my personal account (which has a long, impossible to remember password + OTP and it's a pain to login/logout all the time).

There's a way to have multiple logins? (Firefox extensions OK)

I read about aliases, but it looks like it's just for sending emails.

Comment: Using a different browser works for Google accounts - it may for Yahoo, too.

Comment: No, I only have firefox on my computer

Comment: You should be able to have at least two logins at the same time: Once you login in a normal Firefox window, open a Private Window (_File -> New Private Window_), and use that window to login with the second account.